# WP REST API Filter param being ignored

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

I'm trying to filter posts by category using this this:
`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]=118`

Regarding the current documentation, this should be the way to go, but it seems like all `?filter` params are getting ignored.

I've tried different filtering like `?category_name=`, etc

Do you have any idea why this happens?
Thanks you!